# adsense rubyonrails 5 project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, adsense, turbolinks

I've spent the past month trying to get ads on my web app to just be told by a guy in a google forum that Adsense doesn't work with apps.

Is this true? Sounds strange. I couldn't find a convincing answer one way or another.

If Adsense doesn't work on Ruby on Rails 5 how can I easily get ads on my app? Is there a gem? I feel like this would be a common question, but I couldn't get it answered in my google searches so I've come to you SO.

Please help!

Please checkout www.eduly.in and go inspect element to see error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybC8r.png

Comment: Have you applied for an adsense account at some point and be rejected? (even if you later applied again and got it).

Comment: @Brad This is very old adsense account so i don't remember any thing like that.

Answer (score 0):

This often happens if you have applied for an adsense account previously but be rejected (even if you later got accepted).

Steps to resolve:

1) Double check the code on your site is the exact same as the code being generated in adsense. View source of your page or inspect (as per your screenshot).

2) Make sure your website is added to your adsense account. In adsense go to the Gear icon -> Settings -> My sites -> Manage sites and add your website.

Click the three dots icon and select authorization and check if ” Only Authorize my verified sites to use my ad code” is  off.

3) Check with your hosting service:

Certain hosting services like Namecheap would have a mod rule applied. If you report them this issue, then they will whitelist your domain.

4) If your website uses CloudFlare , then you must make sure that you switch off the Rocketscript . Because  Rocketscript will break AdSense code from displaying. Go to your CloudFlare account, go to Speed tab and check if the Rocket Loader is Off.

reference: https://www.shoutmeloud.com/adsense-403-forbidden-error.html#

5) As a rails specific test, can you try turning off turbolinks and see if that makes any difference? and report back if it does.

Comment: I have tried all the method which u provided but none of them working right now.

Comment: How many days it take to google to display ads on to website?